# Why can't a function be called from v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to call getName() to change the table value. But the function is not called. 
It just seems to fetch values ​​directly from headers.
How can I change the value by calling getName()?

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="studies" :search="search" @click:row="detail">
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ getName(props.item.user) }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.createdAt }}</td>
        </template>
</v-data-table>
```

```
headers: [
      {
        text: 'Title',
        value: 'title',
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: 'Name',
        value: 'user',
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Created',
        value: 'createdAt',
        sortable: false
      }
    ]
```

```
getName(val) {
      this.$axios.get("http://localhost:3000/users/" + val).then(res => {
           this.name = res.data.name;
         });
      console.log(this.name);
      return this.name;
    },
```

Comment: what's the version of your vuetify

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The vuetify version is 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

It is explicitly stated in vuetify's documentation that `click:row` will not be emitted when table rows are defined through slots like `item` or `body` as you did in your code above. Check the link below and go through events available to Vuetify's data table.

[Link to Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots)

Instead you can render your table like so, Then if you need to add any custom method or action to any of the values.

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="studies" :search="search" @click:row="detail">

  <template v-slot:item.title="{ item }">
    <v-chip>{{ item.title }}</v-chip>
  </template>

</v-data-table>
```

Make sure the prop come in this format

```
[
  {title: "Java 101", user:"anon_User", createdAt:"new Date()"},
  {title: "Vue3", user:"root_user", createdAt:"new Date(7)"},
]
```